# Difference between multiple inheritance and interfaces in c#

Tags: c#, .net

Does c# really support multiple inheritance. People say it supports multiple inheritance in the form of interfaces ? But I dont think so

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the literal sense, it does not support multiple inheritance.  It can *implement* multiple interfaces, which offer polymorphic behaviour, so get you some benefits of multiple inheritance.  However you get no base behaviour.

If you need the base behaviour a common tactic is for a base class to implement the interfaces and for derived classes to override this implementation where required.

I have yet to run into the need for multiple inheritance, I don't think C# suffers for the lack of it.

Comment: I was about to add this and your answer came through.
Multiple Inheritance is not supported in C#. Since Interfaces do not define a default behaviour. However, you can inherit from multiple contracts (Interfaces).

Comment: Multiple object inheritance is not supported in the CLR either.  I have seen places were multiple inheritannce would be nice... but I it forces you do create objects that are easier for others to maintain.

Comment: The only time I've been bitten by this is when a type doesn't extend MarshalByRefObject.

Comment: @Will ah yea, forgot about that one - I've had that once before, but only the once :)

Answer (score 1):

In theory of object oriented languages, there are two concepts that are often mixed together when talking about inheritance in C#/Java/etc.

**Subtyping** means that a single class can be written in a way that it can be casted to (or viewed as) some other simpler type (called *supertype*). In C# terms, this means that you can pass an object to a method where a parent class or an interface is expected. An object in C# can clearly have multiple supertypes (parent + as many interfaces as you want)

**Subclassing** means that a type inherits implementation from some other type. In C# this happens when you have a parent class, but not when you're implementing an interface (because you don't inherit any implementation from the interface). So, C# allows you to have only a single superclass (=parent class).

Answer (score 0):

Implementation over delegation (IOD) is a very simple coding techniques which allows a developers fast implementation of an system interfaces and *multiple inheritance* in C# (I know:It is not supported :))

Well the whole idea is basically to have a class field of desired type and to expose functionality public properties of the class based on hidden calls to the member field

So if we have something like Class A and Class B are parents of a Class C.An example of that situation could be the case when we would have a user control which should be able to handle and present a list of customers

Because user control and List are bot classes you couldn't do that directly, by inheriting, because there is no support for multiple inheritance in the case of c# (and I'm happy with that because I think multiple inheritance when not properly used very often leads to class explosion anti pattern)

Answer (score 0):

The language designers decided not to allow multiple inheritance in C#. It has been [discussed before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995255/why-is-multiple-inheritance-not-allowed-in-java-or-c).