# why is multi-level, multiple inheritance removed in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is Multiple Inheritance not allowed in Java or C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995255/why-is-multiple-inheritance-not-allowed-in-java-or-c)

Can anyone explain why cannot we use multiple inheritance, multi-level inheritance, hybrid inheritance in asp.net C#, but Framework was built with reference to OOPS concept available in C++, C++ has multiple, multi-level, hybrid inheritance.

We can find the examples in many books of C++, i want know what exactly made us to avoid such types of inheritance, and due to this we started using, Interfaces, Shadowing, etc concepts in C#.

Any single detail will help me to research on this topic,

Thanks

Comment: May i request you to explain why are you voting down. I may not be so talent as you are but atleast explain so we learn from our questions

Comment: Agree with Murtaza, if you downvote, explain the reason..otherwise we are going to loose beginners who are just learning to ask questions.

Comment: @Murtaza, the downvotes are not mine (although the close vote is), but I'll go out on a limb here and say people thought you could have researched that topic a little further before asking. Googling for `why no multiple inheritance in c sharp` gives plenty of results, including the aforementioned dupe and MSDN article.

Comment: @Murtaza: such feature was never removed from asp.net. It wasn't even removed from C#. It wasn't even removed from the CLR. It just never existed and has nothing to do with ASP.Net. This question as it stands will spread confusion only, which is why it should be edited or disappear: it has not future merit as it is now.

Comment: I voted to close because this question serves no specific, immediate programming need. It's just an invitation to "discussion" and speculation and opinions.

Answer (score 0):

C# obviously supports multi-level inheritance though it doesn't support Multiple Implementation Inheritance directly but they do support Multiple Interface Inheritance. For further clarification look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/07/why-doesn-t-c-support-multiple-inheritance.aspx) link. I hope this will clear your doubts. Cheers !!!