# Is this Multiple inheritance in java?Why not Java supports extends ChildOne,ChildTwo syntax?

Tags: java

I have three classes

**ChildTwo**

```
public class ChildTwo {
    public void methodOfChildTwo() {
        System.out.println("methodOfChildTwo.");
    }
}
```

**ChildOne which extends ChildTwo**

```
public class ChildOne extends ChildTwo{
    public void methodOfChildOne() {
        System.out.println("methodOfChildOne.");
    }
}
```

**Parent which extends ChildOne**

```
public class Parent extends ChildOne{
    public void methodOfParent() {
        System.out.println("methodOfParent.");
    }
}
```

When I create object of Parent, I can call all the three methods as all those methods are inherited in Parent class.

```
Parent parent =new Parent();
parent.methodOfParent();
parent.methodOfChildOne();
parent.methodOfChildTwo();
```

My questions are

1. Can I say this way I can achieve multiple inheritance in Java?
2. This approach is **conceptually** similar with multiple extends, like
   `Parent extends ChildOne,ChildTwo` (Java does not supports these syntax). Why Java does not supports this syntax, although we can achieve this in above mentioned way?

Please someone clarify.

Comment: Multiple inheritance would be having `Child` extend both `Father` and `Mother`.  How would you achieve that?

Comment: Multiple inheritance is something like `.<:`; what you have here is `.-.-.`. Dots represent classes, `<` and `-` represent inheritance. If you wanted an extremely rough textual explanation.

Comment: It does not support it because if both ChildOne and ChildTwo had the same method, how does it determine which method is kept and which is ignored.  It may seem easy but some people may see it make sense one way over the other.  By keeping it simple and just allowing single inheritance, things are kept simpler

Comment: It's as conceptually similar as (Grandmother, Mother, Daughter) and (Mother, Father, Daughter).

Comment: my Parent class extend two classes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Multiple Inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824402/java-multiple-inheritance)

Comment: It only extends one class.  The class that it extended, extends from another class

Answer (score 2):

First of all Java does not support multiple inheritance because it may cause ambiguity. (Note: language like C++ does support multiple inheritance).

> 1.Can I say this way I can achieve multiple inheritance in Java?

This is still not multiple inheritance.

**See my diagram below:**

[image]

Your given code is like the diagram on the *right hand side*. Multiple inheritance will inherit all properties and behaviours directly from all its parents (Not supported in Java).

> 2.This approach is conceptually similar with multiple extends, like Parent extends ChildOne,ChildTwo (Java does not supports these syntax).

Your approach is actually not conceptually similar with multiple extends. Java does not support this to prevent ambiguity. Imagine both parent class has a method of similar signature.

```
class Bomb{
    public void activate();
}

class LightBulb{
    public void activate();
}

class Child extends Bomb, LightBulb{  //Imagine if this is allowed
    //When I call activate(), will it activate the bomb or the lightBulb?
}
```

> Why Java does not supports this syntax, although we can achieve this in above mentioned way?

Both cases are different, you can't achieve multiple inheritance by `a extends b`, `b extends c`. Conceptually it is different because the hierarchy is totally different.

In multiple inheritance, both parent class which you want to extends to can be totally **unrelated**. Imagine `Pegasus extends FlyingCreature, Horse`.

`Pegasus` **is** a `FlyingCreature`, it **is** also a `Horse`, but `FlyingCreature` and `Horse` are **not related** at all.

In your given example, all subsequent exntended parent classes is a subset of another. They are all **related**.

`Mammal` **is**  `Animal` and `Lion` **is** `Mammal` and **is** also `Animal.`

---

If you say your mentioned approach is conceptually similar to multiple inheritance, think of this scenario:

You are tasked to create `class Pegasus` from `class FlyingCreature` & `class Horse`.

**Are you going to do this?**

```
class FlyingCreature{
}

class Horse extends FlyingCreature{   //But Horses do not fly!
}

class Pegasus extends Horse{  //You got what you want here, but the Horse class is wrong.
}
```

**Or this?**

```
class Horse{
}

class FlyingCreature extends Horse{   //All flying creatures are horses? Are you sure?
}

//You got what you want here, but the FlyingCreature class is wrong.
class Pegasus extends FlyingCreature {
}
```

So now you see, it can't be done because both parent class are not related at all. To somewhat achieve so called "*multiple inheritance*", Java use `interface`.

Answer (score 0):

See this thread about the same problem: [Why is Multiple Inheritance not allowed in Java or C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995255/why-is-multiple-inheritance-not-allowed-in-java-or-c)

The best answer is too much trouble for so little benefits. You can pratically made the same things with the interfaces.

You can implements multiple interfaces, so there is no need to have multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

A `Dog` is both a `Mammal` and a `Pet`. Yet `Pet` is not `Mammal`. You cannot model the relationship between `Mammal`, `Pet`, and `Dog` using only Java classes. This is because Java does not support multiple inheritance.

The above is *not* conceptually similar to the relationship between `Animal`, `Mammal`, and `Dog`, which is something Java supports. This is why your "although" part of the question is a non-sequitur.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not conceptually similar.

While `Parent` has extended `ChildOne` which in turn extends `ChildTwo` and inherited methods from both, it causes following problem:

```
ChildOne[] arr = new ChildOne[2];
arr[0] = new ChildOne();
arr[1] = new ChildTwo(); // <--- this should have failed
```

Assuming that `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo` are supposed to be mutually exclusive, the last assignment `arr[1] = c2` should have failed with an ArrayStoreException.

Answer (score 0):

The one you explained is "Multilevel Inheritance".

Multilevel Inheritance -> B extends A. C extends B.
Multiple Inheritance -> P extends Q, R. This is not allowed in java. For multiple inheritance we use Interfaces. As a class can implement any number of interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is multilevel inheritence, not multiple inheritance.

Think of inheritance like having parents. You inherit what your parents have, and in turn inherit what they got from their grandparents. You wouldn't call that multiple inheritance, would you?

Multiple class inheritance would be like getting genes from your parents and then other parents (from a different family tree). Doesn't make sense in real life because what if you got duplicate genes? If you got blue eye genes from one set of parents and green eye genes from your other parents, which would you pick?

It's the same thing in Java:

Here's a simple example:

```
public class A {
    public void doSomething() {
        // Does something
    }
}

public class B {
    public void doSomething() {
        // Does something else
    }
}

public class C extends A,B {
    ....
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    C newC = new C();
    newC.doSomething();
    // PROBLEM!
}
```

Which `doSomething()` should be picked? There's no way to tell! So Java avoids this problem (and many others I'm sure) by not allowing multiple superclasses.