# About the Multiple Inheritance in java? Since Java Doesn't support Multiple Inheritance

Tags: java

For eg:
Case 1: Does every Java class we create will extend `Object` class and if so then how come we an able to extend one more class to our class may be silly question just got it in mind i am posting this question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's easily found by searching

Comment: Haha @mastah; sunlight is the best disinfectant.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple:
The hierarchy of java-classes is tree-like, with `Object` as root. If a class doesn't extend any other class it directly extends `Object` by default. So what about classes that extend some other class, like `class A extends B`. Now `A` extends `B` **and** `Object`. But this **is not** multiple inheritance. `A` extends `B`, thus `A` aswell extends any superclass of `B`, including `Object`. Just imagine the inheritance this way:

```
                       Object
                      /   |   \
                     B   ...   SomeObject
                     |
                     A
```

Comment: I think talking about a tree is confusing in this case. What we are interested in is the parent classes of a given class (they are literally the classes we inherit from), ant that's never a tree in Java

Comment: well, if you want to look at it this way... . Nevertheless the overall structure is a tree. And for multiple-inheritance, even if we look at the relationship between superclasses of a given class, it's still a graph. Just assume the following relationship: `D`, `C extends D`, `B extends D`, `A extends B,C`. That's no tree, but still a valid inheritance-relationship in a language allowing multiple inheritance

Comment: Mmm that's true, parents can form a graph for multiple inheritance

Answer (score 2):

Yes every class extends `Object`. However, `Object` is not necessarily the *direct* superclass. If a class `Child` extends `Parent`, then `Child`'s direct superclass is `Parent`. In this case, the class hierarchy is:

```
Child < Parent < Object
```

So there is no multiple inheritance for `Child`. `Object` is inherited transitively by its direct superclass `Parent`.

Answer (score 1):

No offense, but your english makes your question very difficult to read. I think I understood it though. *Multiple inheritance* is not the contrary of *inheriting only from one class*. You can inherit from several classes and still not have multiple inheritance.

For example, C inherit from A and B if `A extends B, B extends C`. However, the inheritance is a linear chain here, whereas multiple inheritance allows for trees, for example `A extends B, A extends C`. This is different, as you see. In java, you can inherit from as many classes as you like by **transitivity** but directly extend only  one class.

Comment: normal inheritance allows trees. multiple inheritance actually allows graph-like inheritance-chains

Comment: ...the diamond of death!

Comment: The ancestors of a node (in your tree) will always be a linear chain, not a tree. See my comment on your answer. You are right about the graph and all, but I find it clearer to talk about the linearity of the ancestors than to consider other unrelated classes which form a tree together

Answer (score 1):

Multiple inheritance is when you try to inherit more than a class at the same time,

I mean like

```
class Foo extends Faa, Fii {
}
```

that is not posible in Java but we can have this

```
class Faa{
} 

class Fii extends Faa{
}

class Foo extends Fii{

}
```

that is not the same, in that case we have 2 parents (i mean Fii because we are extending from Fii and Faa because Fii extends from it)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31349072/is-this-multiple-inheritance-in-javawhy-not-java-supports-extends-childone-chil

Comment: yes your right ricco thanks so much