# Extend concrete base class of hierarchy

Tags: java, oop

Say I was using a library for shapes which offered:

```
class Shape
class Circle extends Shape
class Square extends Shape
```

but I want introduce the concept of red shapes. I cannot modify the library but I can create:

```
class RedShape extends Shape
```

however this cannot be easily extended to `RedCircle` as it cannot extend both `RedShape` and `Circle`.

I don't think the decorator pattern quite works here but is there a technique for achieving this?

Comment: I think the decorator pattern is actually your best choice in this case, as you can't have multiple inheritance

Answer (score 1):

Short answer can be found in [Effective java](https://github.com/HackathonHackers/programming-ebooks/blob/master/Java/Effective%20Java%20(2nd%20Edition).pdf) by Josh Bloch, *Item 16: Favor composition over inheritance*.

---

**EDIT**: Composition is what you would need to do, really. [Multiple inheritance is not allowed with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995255/why-is-multiple-inheritance-not-allowed-in-java-or-c). People have [tried](http://How%20to%20inherit%20from%20multiple%20base%20classes%20in%20Java). They have some [approaches](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072159/core-java/simulate-multiple-inheritance-in-java.html). They are [writing papers](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cpe.703/abstract) about it. They even use code generating tools, or proxy (not jdk proxy in your case, it cannot make proxy of a class), but nothing is as elegant as you would probably like.

Comment: This should probably be a comment. Alternatively, you could give us some insight into this "short answer" in addition to the link :)

Comment: I don't think composition is the answer in this case as `RedShape` still need to be a `Shape` for example so I can `draw(Shape)` it.

Comment: Well, you can't _draw_ a shape unless you know what to draw; in other words, abstractness of a shape is captured by its `draw` method. So, I am hoping that this hypothetical library makes `Shape#draw` an `abstract` method.

Answer (score 0):

Define an interface `Colorable` with methods `getColor` and `setColor` and have colored shapes implement it.