# Why this code does NOT represent multiple inheritance in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

When we create a type in C#, i.e., `A` class, it automatically inherits from `object`.

Now this class can be inherited by another class.

So we have a hierarchy like this:

```
object : Class A : Class B
```

Technically Class `B` is inheriting Class `A` and `object`.

When this is possible, why is this not:

```
class C : A, B
```

Comment: I think you can look this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995255/why-is-multiple-inheritance-not-allowed-in-java-or-c

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are trying to ask? Clearly you know that C# does not support multiple inheritance... So what exactly you looking for in this question?

Comment: The first part of your question doesn't have any bearing on the second. You describe single inheritance, then ask why multiple inheritance isn't allowed. `Technically Class B is inheriting Class A and object.` in a hierarchy, not at the same time.

Comment: Your first example is allowed in the C# spec. The second is not.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli it does. I am trying to understand when every class can inherit from object ideally any user crated class when inherited by another class is already inheriting from two classes (object and Class A).

Comment: "is already inheriting from two classes (object and Class A)". It's not. A inherits from object. B inherits from A.

Comment: @Codehelp If my father inherits money from his father when he dies, he is free to do whatever he wants with that money when he dies, right? If he elects to leave all of his belongings to me, I get his belongings and the money that he inherited, right? That isn't the same as both of them electing to leave money to me, is it? By the same logic, `ClassB` is only inheriting from `ClassA`, and `ClassA` is inheriting from `object`. `ClassB` still gets all of `object`, but this is not multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## No; Multi-class inheritance (multiple inheritance) is not supported in C#.

## Yes; Every type in .NET derives from `Object` (directly or indirectly).

The way you are understanding this is incorrect; this is NOT multi-class inheritance. This is multi-level inheritance.

Take the following example:

```
class A : Object

class B : A //This is what happens = Correct = Multi-level inheritance

class B : A, Object//This is what you are thinking = Incorrect = Multi-class inheritance.
```

Yes, class `A` derives from `Object`.
Yes, class `B` derives from `A`; but class `B` does NOT **directly** derive from `Object`.

As class `A` is derived from `Object`, all exposed members of `Object` are accessible to `A`. As class `B` is derived from `A`, all exposed members of `A` are accessible to `B`. That is why, all exposed members of `Object` are also accessible to class `B`.

This way, class `B` is also derived from `Object` **indirectly**. This is multi-level inheritance.

That is why your following statement is correct:

> Class B also derives from object. Every type in .NET does.

Just a slight correction:

**All types in .NET are *directly* derived from `Object` if they are not derived from another type. If they are derived from another type, then they are *indirectly* derived from `Object`. Yes, in any case, each type is derived from `Object`.**

Answer (score 2):

Taking cue from your example, Class A inherits Object class which in turn is inherited by Class B it is not multiple inheritance but multilevel inheritence. In case you override a function in class A it is the overrided function which will be inherited in class B not the function of class A

[image: Inheritance example]

I took this image from this page
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/inheritance