# Could interfaces in C# be replaced by abstract classes with no data fields?

Tags: c#, interface

If C# allowed inheritance from multiple classes, provided that at most one of them had data fields, interfaces would be redundant.

Such field-less abstract classes would be superior to interfaces in many ways. For example we could have default implementations (coming as a new language feature only in C# 8.0), or utility methods related to the interface. The language would be simpler with one concept less.

Comment: Unlike C++, C# *doesn't allow* multiple inheritance

Comment: Since C# doesn't allow it, what exactly is the question?

Comment: Adding multiple inheritance would make the language more complex.  For instance if both parent classes have the same method then which one gets called on the child?

Comment: You should post this at the C# Specification GitHub, there's nothing we can do here.

Comment: The question is more about language design than solving actual problem. Is there any reason C# was not designed that way?

Comment: Sure, you may want to try Google: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995255/why-is-multiple-inheritance-not-allowed-in-java-or-c

Comment: in C# 8 interfaces have default implementation

Answer (score 3):

No, the language  would not be simpler - on the contrary:

- Readers of your code would have no idea if your abstract class has fields or not, so they would have to read your code to see if you are sharing an interface or an implementation
- Interfaces could be implemented by value types. You would have to make an exception for "fieldless" abstract classes, or create an `abstract struct` to replace `interface`
- An extension method could be employed in place of a default implementation to share code "horizontally"
- Since adding fields to an abstract class would make it ineligible for multiple inheritance, expanding the base class would break derived classes.

That is a pretty high price to pay for dropping a keyword from the language.